# Anyone could/might get very nasty skin disease

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider these sentences:

1. Anyone **could/might** get a very nasty skin disease from bathing in dirty water.
2. John **could/might** get a very nasty skin disease from bathing in dirty water.
3. I **could/might** get a very nasty skin disease from bathing in dirty water.

Q1) If (1) is given, can I conclude (2) and (3)?

Q2) Are they all general statements about possibility that do not refer to any particular time, ie, true for any and all time?

**Note**: Not asking about the difference between "could" and "might"?

Comment: Of course you are asking about the difference. That is the only question that makes sense....

Comment: Is "John" a human?  If John is a robot then 2 might not be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Anyone" is a very large group of people. Both **John** and **myself** are included in "anyone," so if you say "Anyone could experience *X*" it follows that either John or myself could experience *X*.

As @Lambie points out, you are asking about the difference between *could* and *might* by asking your second question. I would say: "I *could* get a disease" is more general and covers a longer time frame, while "I *might* get a disease" is more limited: It's possible I could contract this disease, but if I haven't shown symptoms in three weeks I'll consider myself out of danger.

Comment: Thank you. 1) But from "Anyone **might** experience X", does it follow that: "John or myself **might** experience X"? 2) Is sentence (1) in the OP true for all time, both with "could" and "might"?

Comment: @Mr.X 1) yes, 2) see my answer...

Comment: One last question: In your sentence: *It's possible I **could** contract this disease, but if I haven't shown symptoms in three weeks I'll consider myself out of danger.* Can I replace the "could" with "can"?

Comment: @Mr.X yes. Look in a dictionary to see the different nuances between the two words.